# Images are blurry when rotate the screen android device with Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I use glide to load the drawable image in the adapter (the error occurred with the image not located in recyclerview):

`Glide.with (holder.ivPreview) .load (mThemeDrawableIds.get (position)).into (holder.ivPreview)`

When recording mThemeDrawableIds will be reloaded and notify again. However, the image is blurred compared to the original image.

I tried clearing the cache but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to also add android:adjustViewBounds="true" to your ImageView in XML.

Also try this code :

```
Glide.with(imageView).load(mThemeDrawableIds.get (position))
.apply(new RequestOptions()
        .fitCenter()
        .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
        .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL))
.into(holder.ivPreview);
```